# Authentication Provider : SecurityProvider service class name for XXXX is not specified in WL 12.1.3.0.0

Tags: java, security, authentication, weblogic12c

I've just created an Authentication Provider for WebLogic Server Version 12.1.3.0.0, (The Authentication Provider adheres to the standard JAAS framework by structuring the authentication sequence on top of a number of configurable JAAS LoginModules. ) but when I start Wl I have this error:

Here the steps:

1) set ENV

```
%WL_HOME%/server/bin/setWLSEnv.cmd
```

2)  generate the MBean and stubs:

```sh
java -cp %WL_HOME%/server/lib/* -verbose -DcreateStubs="true" \
weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker -MDF WSAuthentication.xml \
-files C:\Development\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider\src
```

3) package the authentication provider and login module with the generated stub and MBI files.

```
java -DMJF=C:\Development\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider\jar\WSAuthentication.jar \
-Dfiles=C:\Development\Workspaces\Eclipse\WLAuthenticationProvider\src weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker
```

4) add -DUseSunHttpHandler=true to startWebLogic.cmd

```
weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:090877]Service Common JAASAuthenticationService unavailable, see exception text: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for MyAuthentication is not specified.
        at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.initialize(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:155)
        at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.<init>(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:315)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doATN(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:731)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:515)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postLoadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:861)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:927)
        at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1109)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.postInitialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:943)
        at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:159)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1017)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:388)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:430)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:606)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:77)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:231)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:254)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:413)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:456)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:225)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:82)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2488)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:98)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:553)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: com.bea.common.engine.ServiceInitializationException: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for TntWS2Authentication is not specified.
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:365)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:315)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.lookupService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:257)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServicesImpl.getService(ServicesImpl.java:72)
        at weblogic.security.service.CSSWLSDelegateImpl.getService(CSSWLSDelegateImpl.java:155)
        at com.bea.security.css.CSS.getService(CSS.java:123)
        at weblogic.security.service.PrincipalAuthenticator.initialize(PrincipalAuthenticator.java:132)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: com.bea.common.engine.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:097533]SecurityProvider service class name for MyAuthentication is not specified.
        at com.bea.common.security.internal.legacy.service.SecurityProviderImpl.init(SecurityProviderImpl.java:42)
        at com.bea.common.engine.internal.ServiceEngineImpl.findOrStartService(ServiceEngineImpl.java:363)
        ... 52 more
```

Here my file MyAuthentication.xml (A simple MDF (MyAuthentication.xml) for an authentication provider). WebLogic's provider architecture is MBean-based

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE MBeanType SYSTEM "commo.dtd">
<MbeanType 
        Name = "MyAuthentication" 
        DisplayName = "MyAuthentication"
        Package = "fr.telecom.devices.ws.security.iap"
        Extends = "weblogic.management.security.authentication.Authenticator"
        PersistPolicy = "OnUpdate"  >

<MbeanAttribute 
        Name = "ProviderClassName" 
        Type = "java.lang.String"
        Writeable = "false"
        Default ="&quot;fr.telecom.devices.ws.security.iap.MyAuthenticationProviderImpl&quot;"
      />

    <MbeanAttribute Name = "Description" Type = "java.lang.String"
      Writeable = "false"
      Default = "&quot;Traces Authentication Provider&quot;"
      />

    <MBeanAttribute Name = "Version" Type = "java.lang.String"
      Writeable = "false" Default = "&quot;1.0&quot;"
      />

</MbeanType>
```

and here the file META-INF\binding-file.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns:binding-config xmlns:ns="http://www.bea.com/ns/staxb/binding-config/90">
  <ns:bindings>
    <ns:binding-type xsi:type="ns:by-name-bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns:xmlcomponent>t=tnt-ws2-authenticationType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
      <ns:qname-property>
        <ns:xmlcomponent>t=string@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</ns:xmlcomponent>
        <ns:javatype>java.lang.String</ns:javatype>
        <ns:getter>
          <ns:method-name>getName</ns:method-name>
        </ns:getter>
        <ns:setter>
          <ns:method-name>setName</ns:method-name>
          <ns:param-type>java.lang.String</ns:param-type>
        </ns:setter>
        <ns:issetter>
          <ns:method-name>isNameSet</ns:method-name>
        </ns:issetter>
        <ns:qname xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security">sec:name</ns:qname>
        <ns:nillable>true</ns:nillable>
      </ns:qname-property>
      <ns:qname-property>
        <ns:xmlcomponent>t=string@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</ns:xmlcomponent>
        <ns:javatype>java.lang.String</ns:javatype>
        <ns:getter>
          <ns:method-name>getCompatibilityObjectName</ns:method-name>
        </ns:getter>
        <ns:setter>
          <ns:method-name>setCompatibilityObjectName</ns:method-name>
          <ns:param-type>java.lang.String</ns:param-type>
        </ns:setter>
        <ns:issetter>
          <ns:method-name>isCompatibilityObjectNameSet</ns:method-name>
        </ns:issetter>
        <ns:qname xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security">sec:compatibility-object-name</ns:qname>
        <ns:nillable>true</ns:nillable>
      </ns:qname-property>
      <ns:qname-property>
        <ns:xmlcomponent>t=string@http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</ns:xmlcomponent>
        <ns:javatype>java.lang.String</ns:javatype>
        <ns:getter>
          <ns:method-name>getControlFlag</ns:method-name>
        </ns:getter>
        <ns:setter>
          <ns:method-name>setControlFlag</ns:method-name>
          <ns:param-type>java.lang.String</ns:param-type>
        </ns:setter>
        <ns:issetter>
          <ns:method-name>isControlFlagSet</ns:method-name>
        </ns:issetter>
        <ns:qname xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security">sec:control-flag</ns:qname>
        <ns:nillable>true</ns:nillable>
      </ns:qname-property>
    </ns:binding-type>
    <ns:binding-type xsi:type="ns:simple-document-binding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ns:xmlcomponent>e=tnt-ws2-authentication@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
      <ns:type-of-element>t=tnt-ws2-authenticationType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:type-of-element>
    </ns:binding-type>
  </ns:bindings>
  <ns:xml-to-pojo>
    <ns:mapping>
      <ns:xmlcomponent>t=tnt-ws2-authenticationType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
    </ns:mapping>
    <ns:mapping>
      <ns:xmlcomponent>e=tnt-ws2-authentication@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
    </ns:mapping>
  </ns:xml-to-pojo>
  <ns:xml-to-xmlobj/>
  <ns:java-to-xml>
    <ns:mapping>
      <ns:xmlcomponent>t=tnt-ws2-authenticationType@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
    </ns:mapping>
  </ns:java-to-xml>
  <ns:java-to-element>
    <ns:mapping>
      <ns:xmlcomponent>e=tnt-ws2-authentication@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/extension</ns:xmlcomponent>
      <ns:javatype>eu.cec.sanco.tracesnt.ws.security.iap.TntWS2AuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
    </ns:mapping>
  </ns:java-to-element>
</ns:binding-config>
```

this is the structure os the project

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be many reasons, but I guess it is a package problem. Please, check if your resulting provider `.jar` contains a file called `META-INF/binding-file.xml` and check if this file has `bindind` node as follows:

```
<ns:binding-type xsi:type="ns:by-name-bean" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns:xmlcomponent>t=custom-ldapdb-bean-apType@your.namespaces</ns:xmlcomponent>
    <ns:javatype>fr.telecom.devices.ws.security.iap.MyAuthenticationMBeanImpl</ns:javatype>
```

`your.namespace` must be defined in `build.xml` into `WebLogicMBeanMAker` as `-target` parameter.

Tell me also if your resulting provider `.jar` looks like this

```
.
├── commo.dtd
├── MyAuthentication-Mbean.xml
├── fr
│   └── telecom
│       └── devices
│           └── ws
│               └── security
│                   └── iap
│                       ├── impl
│                       │   ├── MyAuthenticationProviderImpl.class
│                       │   ├── ...
│                       │   └── ...
│                       └── mbeans
│                           ├── MyAuthenticationImpl.class
│                           ├── MyAuthenticationMBean.class
│                           ├── MyAuthenticationImplBeanInfo.class
│                           ├── MyAuthenticationMBeanImpl.class
│                           ├── MyAuthentication$Helper.class
│                           └── MyAuthentication$SchemaHelper2.class
├── META-INF
│   ├── beaninfofactory.txt
│   ├── binding-file.ser
│   ├── binding-file.xml
│   ├── binding-mapping-file.ser
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── schemas
│       └── schema-0.xsd
├── schemacom_bea_xml
│   ├── element
│   │   └── your_2Enamespace
│   │       └── my_2Dauthentication_2Dap.xsb
│   ├── namespace
│   │   └── your_2Enamespace
│   │       └── xmlns.xsb
│   ├── system
│   │   └── sED25F267F5545F2AED6F8F098FF3212F
│   │       ├── myauthentication94aadoctype.xsb
│   │       ├── myauthentication.xsb
│   │       ├── myauthentication7480type.xsb
│   │       ├── index.xsb
│   │       └── TypeSystemHolder.class
│   └── type
│       └── es_2Esescam_2Eprovider
│           └── my_2Dauthentication2DapType.xsb
└── weblogic
      ├── descriptor
      │   └── SettableBean.class
      └── management
          └── security
              └── LDAP_DB_WLS12C_PROVIDER18595502884856BeanInfoFactory.class
```

If your are missing something I would like to know what is that.

## Edit

I edit my answer in response to your comment, and answer edition.

I can see in your `META-INF\binding-file.xml` there is no custom namespace in `<ns:xmlcomponent>` node.

To specify `targetNamespace` in the `WebLogicMBeanMaker` command, you can change your command as follows (*It is shown such way for clarity*):

```
java 
  -DMJF=C:\...\...\WLAuthenticationProvider\jar\WSAuthentication.jar \
  -Dfiles=C:\...\...\WLAuthenticationProvider\src \ 
  -DtargetNameSpace= your.own.namespace \
  weblogic.management.commo.WebLogicMBeanMaker
```

Comment: I am not using the file WebLogicMBeanMAker, so where I can set the namespaces ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be also compatible with WebLogic 12.2.x, you need to define "@default" Javadoc annotation for default values, and "@encrypted" Javadoc annotations for encrypted values (passwords, ...)

```
public interface LdapAuthenticatorMBean extends StandardInterface, DescriptorBean, AuthenticatorMBean {

/**
 * @default "com.mycompany.LdapAuthenticatorProviderImpl"
 */
public String getProviderClassName();

/**
 * @no-default 
 * @encrypted
 */
public String getTechPass();
```

and also define setter and getters methods for each property (previously it was not strictly required).

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when I'm going to implement custom authentication provider. There aren't very good tutorials to create custom authentication providers. I tried with the maven and it's working. I found this working tutorial in GitHub. 
[Example Code can be clone here](https://github.com/masini/weblogic-security)

There is an ebook that you can use to get whole idea of creating weblogic custom authentication provider. [Ebook link](https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/securing-weblogic-server-12c-instant)

You may need to change **com.bea.core.common.security.api_1.1.0.0_6-2-0-0.jar** file to this  com.bea.core.common.security.api_1.1.0.0_6-2-0-0.jar

Answer (score 1):

Double check the class name in the `MyAuthenticator.xml` provided

```
fr.telecom.devices.ws.security.iap.MyAuthenticationProviderImpl
```

should be correct with namespaces